# Groovy Script error handling

Tags: groovy

We have the following groovy script. We want to add some error handling to it. Sometimes it can't find the URL api/xml. How can we fix it to handle not erroring out?

```
def parameterName = "FRACTURE_NO";
def jenkinsUrl = System.getenv('JENKINS_URL');
def buildNumber = System.getenv('BUILD_NUMBER').toInteger();
def jobUrl = jenkinsUrl + "job/" + System.getenv('JOB_NAME');
def buildNumberUrl = jobUrl + "/" + buildNumber;
def myParameter = System.getenv(parameterName);

def projectXml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(new URL(jobUrl + "/api/xml").getText());
projectXml.build.each {
  def previousBuildNumber = it.number.text().toInteger();
  if(previousBuildNumber < buildNumber)
  {
    def previousBuildNumberUrl = jobUrl + "/" + previousBuildNumber;
    def jobXml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(new URL(previousBuildNumberUrl + "/api/xml").getText());
    if(jobXml.building.text() == "true")
    {
      jobXml.action.parameter.each {
        if(it.name.text() == parameterName) {
          if(it.value.text() == myParameter) {
            def url = new URL(previousBuildNumberUrl + "/stop?token=spark123");
            def connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + "wscott:26accfcc2cf8a1f3503ac4a70483b4fe".getBytes("UTF-8").encodeBase64());
            connection.setRequestProperty( "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            connection.setRequestProperty( "Accept", "*/*" );
            connection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", 
"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)");
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.connect();
            connection.content.text;
            println "Stopping " + previousBuildNumber;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a try/catch construct. The error is most likely a "FileNotFoundException", that is thrown when http response is 404 (not found). Other errors are likely, so I would be not too specific and catch "IOException", which I think covers all HTTP errors from that call:

```
try {
    String xmlContent = new URL(previousBuildNumberUrl + "/api/xml").getText()
} catch(IOException e) {
    // handle error...
}
```

I think you got a downvote because there is much cruft in this question, that could be abstracted away. Please have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Edit: to answer question below, "IOException" should be enough, but you can use "Exception" instead to catch everything... although that's considered bad practice, because you end up also catching "programming errors" which by definition cannot be handled programmatically. But I have a suspicion that won't be a major concern here.

Comment: What is the exception name called for catching all errors